# Multiple Boxplots in ggplot2 with continuous and categorical data

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot

I have a data frame with 4 columns and 200,000 rows of watershed ID, forest age (categorical 1-4), EVI (continuous), and Drought (categorical "Drought or "Non-Drought"). I am trying to use ggplot to make 10 boxplots for each watershed comparing EVI values in Drought and Non-Drought conditions for that watershed.

Data frame Image: the ID for each watershed is repeated because there are 10,000 EVI samples for each watershed in both drought and non-drought periods

[image: Data frame Image: the ID for each watershed is repeated because there are 10,000 EVI samples for each watershed in both drought and non-drought periods]

This is the code I've been using to try and make these plots with ggplot:

```
box_watershed<-read.table("All_EVI_Watersheds_Boxplot.txt", header=TRUE)        
ggplot(data = box_watershed, aes(x=box_watershed$ID, y=box_watershed$EVI)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=box_watershed$Drought))
    p <- ggplot(data = box_watershed, aes(x=box_watershed$ID, y=box_watershed$EVI)) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=box_watershed$Drought))
    p + facet_wrap( ~ EVI, scales="free")
```

Comment: FYI, don't restate the data frame name inside `aes`. For example, use `ggplot(box_watershed, aes(ID, EVI))`.

Comment: Don't i need to facet wrap though? when i take it out, its only plotting all of the drought vs non-drought values and not making plots per watershed

Comment: The issue is that although watershed is really categorical, it's treated as numeric (i.e., continuous), because the IDs are numbers. So change to `aes(factor(ID), EVI)`. Remove the faceting and you'll get one graph. For each ID, you'll get two boxplots, one for each value of `Drought`.

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much @eipi10! that did the trick!